# How can i float the three wrappers one after the other

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="wrapper1" style="width:200px;float:left;margin-top:0px">
    <img src="./profilepic.jpg"  width="190px" height="220px"/>
</div>
<div id="wrapper2" style="width:400px;float:left">
    <h2>cool</h2>
</div>
<div id="wrapper3" style="width:300px;float:left">
    <h2>Thanks</h2>
</div>
```

These are my three wrappers. I want them to float one after the other, but `wrapper3` is sometimes getting positioned to the bottom of the `wrapper2` , I want `wrapper1` to take 200px and following `wrapper2` 400px and `wrapper3` 300px total 900px.

How can i make them float one after the other in such a way that they occupy 900px?

Comment: can you post a link? I'll try fix it

Comment: that works fine for me, is it any specific browser ur having problems with? Try setting all the margins and padding to 0px on everything

Comment: @Tules try resizing your window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Before I answer

Let me just tell you a few things about good practices and the such.

- It is considered **bad** practice to use inline styling (the `style=` attribute). Use a stylesheet instead (`<style>` tags), it allows the grouping of similar elements and reducing of code. Not to mention the separation of content from presentation.
- the `width=` and `height=` attributes of the `<img>` tags do not require (and in fact do not validate with) the `px` in the end. You should correct to `width="190" height="220"`.

## The Answer

You want to wrap all 3 of them in a container which is set to `width: 900px;` (or `min-width: 900px;` for that matter).

**[Here's an Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TmLPN/)**

### HTML:

```
<div id=parent>
    <div id=wrapper1>Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div id=wrapper2>Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div id=wrapper3>Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
#parent { /* Applies to parent div */
    min-width: 900px;
}
#parent div { /* Applies to all divs within the parent */
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
}

/* Specific div styling (width and background color) */
#wrapper1 {
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
}
#wrapper2 {
    width: 400px;
    background: green;
}
#wrapper3 {
    width: 300px;
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: @niko make sure to read the complete updated answer, including small fixes you should take into account on future projects.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the three divs in a wrapper div with a width 900px and a height 220px.